# Will parameter be removed from ParameterCollection after parametarized query is executed?

Tags: c#, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I have a number of queries in my method. Depending on a conditions, particular query is executed. Each query uses the same parameter.

For example:

```
public static void Method(param1, param2, param3)
{
   ....
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   if(Condition1)
   {
      cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where id=@id"
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", param1);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      foreach(int i in IntegerList)
      {
          ....
          cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table2(id,type,model) values(@id,@type,@model)
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", param1);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          ....       
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cmd.CommandText="select * from Table3 where id = @id"
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", param1);   
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
      da.SelectCommand = cmd;
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      cmd.Dispose();
      da.Dispose();
      ....
   }
   cmd.CommandText = "delete from Table3 where id = @id and model=@model..."
   ....
```

}

My question is will I have an error if I keep adding the parameter `@id` every time I need to execute different query, or my parameter will be deleted after the query executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather add a parameter with type and then set its value when needed. This will make sure the type is always right.

That being said, the parameters are not removed after execution and it seems `AddWithValue` doesn't throw an exception if the key already exists, unlike the previous `Add`. So you should be able to add the parameter again.

Of course if the value is the same and only the query changes you don't need to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your command object first with all parameters and then just assign new values in the loop.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
foreach (...) {
    command.Parameters["@id"].Value = param1; 
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```